# Python networkX save a file as a .drawio file

Tags: python, networkx

I have created a network diagram using networkx library in python and mothplotlib. I would like to be able to  save this as a drawio file, to open with drawio. I was wondering if anyone has done this before
Thanks

```
# Sample draw.io XML file data and file name (replace with your actual data)
drawio_data = b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><mxfile>...</mxfile>'
drawio_filename = "example.drawio"

# Provide a download button for the draw.io file
st.download_button(
    label="Download Draw.io file",
    data=drawio_data,
    key='download-drawio',
    file_name=drawio_filename,
    mime="application/xml"
)
```

Above is the code that I am using

Comment: There's a [`drawio`](https://pypi.org/project/drawio/) library for python, but it doesn't look actively maintained.